# Unable to change the Chapter Number to Roman numeral alone

Tags: lyx, chapters, roman-numerals

When I am using the following command

`\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}`

to set the chapter # to roman. It is also changing the subsection numbering to roman. Do you have any idea, why?

Example: It is showing the Chapter III
and then in the subsection it says

> III.4.1

Please suggest a solution

Comment: `section` counter makes use of the `chapter` counter. So you have that effect.

Comment: It is quite natural, that the (sub)sections should be preceeded by the way the chapter counter is formatted.

Comment: Try this: `\makeatletter\renewcommand\thesection {\@arabic\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}\makeatother`

Comment: If you have chapter V (5), it outputs `III.4.1`???

Comment: @Sigur I don't think you mean that:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I talked about `\thesection` command.

Comment: Maybe this: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thechapter{\@Roman\c@chapter}
\renewcommand\thesection{\@arabic\c@chapter.\@arabic\c@section}
\makeatother`

Comment: The different formatting of the chapter number, `\Roman` vs. `\arabic`, looks like an obfuscating exercise to me. Do you want to make it harder for a potential reader reading the text? For example, 3.4.1 could mean chapter 3, section 4, subsection 1. But I think, the reader might interpret it as section 3, subsection 4, subsubsection 1.

Comment: @Sigur or without the `@`  `\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}`  (but I can't believe the OP wants this if the chapter is using Roman:-)

Comment: Why not just `\renewcommand*\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}`? That seems to me more natural in this case?

Comment: Well, we are here discussing and trying to figure out what the OP wants but he/she didn't come back to read us... lol

Comment: @cfr - I used the \renewcommand*\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}} \renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}} command. And it solved the chapter number problem. But, now all the individual chapter section #'s are beginning with 1. So, now I have 1-5 sections in chapter I and again 1-4 sections in chapter II and son on..

Comment: That is what they normally do ;). So you want continuous section numbering? What about subsections? Those reset with sections but I take it that is OK?

Comment: The subsections are depending on the section # and that seems to be fine. I want to make the sections number to be chapter #.section# -- could you please suggest an alternative?

Comment: Then just use the relevant code offered earlier. That is what Sigur and David Carlisle's code was doing. Why did you use mine if you wanted the chapter number included in the section number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly this??

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{remreset}
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}} \renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{section}{chapter}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

  \chapter{first}
  \section{alpha}
  \subsection{one}
  \subsection{two}
  \section{beta}
  \subsection{one}
  \subsection{two}
  \chapter{second}
  \section{gamma}
  \subsection{one}
  \subsection{two}
  \chapter{third}
  \subsection{one}
  \subsection{two}
  \chapter*{starred}
  \section{delta}
  \subsection{one}
  \subsection{two}
\end{document}
```

[image: complex numbering in bits]

Comment: The main problem with this is I am using a Koma scipt document class which is conflicting with the existing when I use suggestion you mentioned here.

Comment: @hank This is why you should always include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Otherwise, you get useless answers like mine.